# OpenLayers 3: Basic Authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, basic-authentication, openlayers-3

Is it possible to do basic authentication with OpenLayers 3? I found answers that you need to do an ajax-Call and use the token in a "Authentication"-Header.

I wonder if it's possible to tell OpenLayers which header to use because for all my other http-Request I need another Authentication-Header.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a better solution than doing the following:

```
$("<iframe src='https://myWMS.server.com/helloWorld?'/>").on('load', function () {
    createMap();
}
```

If I create the map outside the iframe, I get asked for each tile for a password (because the tiles are loaded asynchronously and don't have the authentication header yet).

So now I send the first request -> get the log-in prompt and the header as a response -> then when I create the map and the tiles are requested they already contain the header.

Comment: By now I've created a Web-API-Proxy through which I route my requests. I can configure the password inside my web.config and let it handle basic authentication without a prompt.